# Toggle between 2 tabs placed in a column on a web page without changing rest of page elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs, togglebutton

I have been asked to create two toggle tabs/buttons within a single column on a web page which a visitor can toggle in between without changing the rest of the page elements. The tabs are meant to look like the Personal and Business tabs at www.vodafone.co.uk but toggling between them should not take you to different web pages.

I first thought this can only be done using JavaScript, but then the top page of www.vodafone.co.uk only uses HTML and CSS to accomplish it although clicking either tab takes you to another web page, which my client does not want. Is there a way to present two tabs which you can click to display different lists without affecting the rest of the page?

Any helpful tips would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Ead

Comment: Could you please [**post the code you currently have**](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? That way we can have a look at it to see where it can be fixed/improved?

Comment: why don't you use 
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/
or 
http://www.menucool.com/jquery-tabs

Answer (score 1):

i will demonstrate the general idea:

html:

```
<input type="button" id="btnSwitch" value="Switch tabs" />
<div class="tab tab1 visible">I'm tab 1</div>
<div class="tab tab2">And i'm tab 2</div>
```

css:

```
.tab{display:none;height:200px;width:200px;border:solid 1px red;}
.tab.tab2{border:solid 1px blue;}
.tab.visible{display:block;}
```

javascript (it's always nicer with jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#btnSwitch').click(function(){ $('.tab').toggleClass('visible') });
});
</script>
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MFfwV/

hope that helps.